# Baby crying till breathless

Tags: newborn, crying, breathing

Some time babies use to cry till breathless. And it take few seconds to start inhale. Seems this activity panicking. Is it natural or do we need to take any action if it go for few seconds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've always called that the "air-raid scream".  You see the baby's face scrunch up and get red while they inhale and then ... WAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH! (much like an air-raid siren).

It's normal.  Every baby I can remember has done this on occasion.  Sometimes they just get extra upset and want your attention NOW.  Once you take care of what's wrong, they will calm down and be happy again.

The only way I could see this causing harm is if you let it go on long enough that they cried until they were hoarse.  As long as you take care of whatever is upsetting them in an at least reasonable time frame, it will be fine.

Comment: Would upvote twice if I could: +1 for the answer, +1 for the “air-raid scream”.